# How to display Visio Document level Shape Data in Sheet Shapes like a text box etc

Tags: visio, shapesheet

I'm trying to create a Visio template file where certain Document level Shape Data is populated and synced by another system. In this template I'm trying to add the value in Document Shape Data "Prop.BS_ID" into a text box using "Insert Field" and "Custom formula". Please see picture below for illustration. With the attemted solution I get "Error in formula).

How can this be done, or is it even possible?

I find a lot of info on different Shape Data into Shapes, but not anything on how to get the Document level Shape Data into a sheet level shape. (If that makes sense). I guess I might be missing some kind of identifier to point to the Document level Shape Dataset, but I'm not able to figure out how. I've tried the obvious "Document." "Document()" etc.

Screen shot showing what I'm trying to do using Document level Shape Data, but does not work:

[image]

Screen shot of equivalent setup, but using shape level Shape Data, working fine:

[image]

Any input will be most appreciated.

Thanks
BR
Fnk

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out after another session of googling.

So to reference the Document level Shape Data you would need to enter the following in the Custom formula field:

```
=TheDoc!Prop.BS_ID
```

The document identifier then being "TheDoc!". And similar, to reference page level shape data, use "ThePage!".

I hope this might help someone else.

Answer found in the comment section of this post:
[Link to VisualSignals' post on Using page Shape Data in Visio master shapes](https://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2012/06/using-page-shape-data-in-visio-master-shapes.html)

Thanks
BR
Frank

Comment: Please add `ShapeSheet tag`